# Android ListView that scrolls from bottom to top?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I'd like to build a ListView that works like a normal ListView, except the first item is on the bottom and grows up, instead of the first item being on the top and growing down.

Of course, I can just use a normal ListView, reverse the order of the adapter, and have it scroll to the last item on the list... but this is inelegant in a number of ways, particularly when adding new rows.

For instance, I would like the ListView to remember the position, but the position from the bottom instead of from the top. So, if they are at the bottom, they should remain at the bottom, but if they are looking 3 up from the bottom, they should still be looking at that item when the new item is added. (Exactly how it works in ListView normally, but reversed.)

Wondering if anybody has any clever tricks to reverse the polarity of an Android ListView?

The classic use case for this would be a list of chat messages, where the most recent one is on the bottom, and items are generally added to the bottom. If someone is at the end of the list, they still want to be at the end of the list when a new message comes in. But if they have scrolled away from the bottom, they don't want their scroll position to be randomly reset.

Comment: do the same reverse the order adapter and scroll to the bottom.. now if new item is added just when you `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` update the activity to scroll to the bottom.. so basically whenever you add a new item it will always scroll to bottom.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is how I am currently doing it. However, this isn't perfect. In a normal ListView, if you scroll away from the top, and the adapter changes, it doesn't always scroll back to the top. It's jarring for the user if they are scrolling up and suddenly pulled back to the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, AbsListView has the attribute:

android:stackFromBottom="true"

which seems to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Note, I still had to add a "scroll to bottom" listener to reposition when the keyboard popped up.